Double quotients of Weyl group
Studying certain incomplete Eisenstein series led me to the following problem. Let $W$ be the Weyl group associated with an irreducible root system $\Phi$, and let $\Pi$ be a set of simple roots. Let $\alpha \in \Pi$ be a simple root that has exactly one neighbor in the corresponding connected Dynkin diagram. Let $W_P$ denote the subgroup of $W$ generated by the reflections associated with the simple roots in $\Pi \setminus \{\alpha\}$.
Is it always true that the cardinality of the set of double cosets $\lvert W_P \backslash W / W_P \rvert = 2$?
I would be grateful for any hints or references.

It is hardly ever true.

I don't think this is true: take for example the Weyl group of type $B_2$, so that $\Pi = \{\alpha,\beta\}$ and if we set $s = s_{\alpha}$ and $t = s_{\beta}$ then $W$ has order $8$:
$$
W = \{e,s,t, st, ts, sts, tst, stst=tsts\}.
$$
Thus if we take $W_P = \langle t \rangle$, then the $W_P\backslash W /W_P$ double cosets are:
$$
W_P = \{\mathbf{e},t\}, \{\mathbf{s},ts,st,tst\}, \{\mathbf{sts},stst=tsts\}
$$
giving 3, not 2, double cosets.
In general, if we let $\ell$ be the length function associated to the generating set $\Pi$, that is $\ell(w)$ is the minimal length of a word in $\Pi$ which evaluates to $w$ in $W$. Let $I\subseteq \Pi$ and set $W_I$ to be the parabolic subgroup of the Weyl group generated by $I$ and $W^I = \{w \in W: \forall s\in I, \ell(w)<\ell(ws) \}$. Then a coset $wW_I$ intersects $W^I$ in exactly one element, so that the cosets are indexed by the elements of $W^I$. One can also check that if $J$ is another subset of $\Pi$ then the double cosets $W_J\backslash W /W_I$ have unique minimal length representatives $^J W^I: = {^{J}}W\cap W^I$ where $^{J}W = \{w \in W: \forall s \in J, \ell(sw)> \ell(w)\}$.

Thanks for taking the time to write this helpful and detailed answer!

No problem! Hopefully the fact that there are natural choices of double-coset representatives is helpful given the situation is more complicated than just having two double cosets.
